# R Shiny- Trying to download a Processed data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to upload 2 files to Rshiny, do a fuzzy match on a column and then download the output in a csv file. I have been succesful in uploading the file and doing the fuzzy match but cant seem to get the download button to work properly. Below is my complete code.

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(DT)


# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    
    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
        
        # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
        sidebarPanel(
            
            # Input: Select a file ----
            fileInput("vendorbrands", "Choose Vendor Brands CSV File",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv")),
            fileInput("smtbrands", "Choose SMT Brand Gaps CSV File",
                      multiple = FALSE,
                      accept = c("text/csv",
                                 "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                 ".csv")),
            #DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
            
            # Horizontal line ----
            tags$hr(),
            
            # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            
            # Input: Select separator ----
            radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                         choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                     Semicolon = ";",
                                     Tab = "\t"),
                         selected = ","),
            
            # Input: Select quotes ----
            radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                         choices = c(None = "",
                                     "Double Quote" = '"',
                                     "Single Quote" = "'"),
                         selected = '"'),
            
            # Horizontal line ----
            tags$hr(),
            
            # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
            radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                         choices = c(Head = "head",
                                     All = "all"),
                         selected = "head"),
            # Output: Download a file ----
            downloadButton("download", "Process the file & Download", class= "action"),
            
            # CSS style for the download button ----
            tags$style(type='text/css', "#downloadFile { width:100%; margin-top: 35px;}")
            
        ),
        
        
        # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
        mainPanel(
            
            # Output: Data file ----
            tableOutput("contents")
            
        )
        
    )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$contents <- renderTable({
        
        # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
        # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
        # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
        
        req(input$vendorbrands)
        
        # when reading semicolon separated files,
        # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
        tryCatch(
            {
                vendor_brands_df <- read.csv(input$vendorbrands$datapath,
                               header = input$header,
                               sep = input$sep,
                               quote = input$quote)
            },
            error = function(e) {
                # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
                stop(safeError(e))
            }
        )
        
        tryCatch(
            {
                smt_brands_df <- read.csv(input$smtbrands$datapath,
                                             header = input$header,
                                             sep = input$sep,
                                             quote = input$quote)
            },
            error = function(e) {
                # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
                stop(safeError(e))
            }
        )
        
        smt_brands_small <- subset(smt_brands_df, select = c("Brand", "Item"))
        vendor_brand_small <- subset(vendor_brands_df,select =c("vendor_code","brand_name"))
        
        output_df <- smt_brands_small %>%
            stringdist_left_join(vendor_brand_small, by=c(Brand="brand_name"), ignore_case=T, method="jw",max_dist=99, distance_col="dist") %>%
            group_by(Brand) %>%
            #top_n(-1) %>%
            top_n(1,-dist)
        
        
        if(input$disp == "head") {
            return(head(output_df))
        }
        else {
            return(output_df)
        }
        
        #sample_data <- reactive({output_df})
        sample_data <- reactive({return(data.frame(output_df))})
        output$table <- renderTable({
            output_Df()
        })
        
        
        
    })
    
    output$download <- downloadHandler(
        
        filename = function() { 
            paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
        },
        
        content = function(file) {
            
            write.csv(sample_data(), file)
            
        })
    
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help on what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Aren't you getting any sort of error message? It seems you are only creating `sample_data` inside the `renderTable()`. That doesn't seem correct. The reactive element needs to be defined in the  main server function body so the `downloadHandler` can see it. You also seem to have nested the table `renderTable` inside the `contents` `renderTable` which doesn't seem correct. Also, be careful case in variable names. You seem to be using both `output_df` and `output_Df` which doesn't seem right.

Comment: No error. Just when i press the download button, an empty file is created. checked all the variable names and made them consistent, still getting the same error